# Why images in XIB are different?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, uiimageview

[image]

At left there's the original image (after imported in Xcode), at right the image inside UIImageView. It's more dark.

Why this? It's a very annoying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Man! Its just an illusion.**

*Don't ask "magic" related questions here. Ask only program related questions* ;-)

Both images are of same color. They look different because ***their background colors are different***.  Use *Photoshop* or some other tool to find the colors of those two. They should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Its because the background colours are different and the stroke on the image is the same / similar colour to the background.

Change the background colour of the view to white, and it will look normal.

Comment: The hex colors is the same but the look is different in the iPhone simulator.